# PHP iDisk\Webdav Client

Tags: php, upload, webdav

I need to upload files to iDisk drive. I've found that iDisk has webdav interface, and it's working fine with desktop clients. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find suitable WebDav client for PHP, and can't find out how to use cUrl to upload files to WebDav. The only [client class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1402-PHP-WebDAV-client-to-access-files-in-a-HTTP-server.html) I've found doesn't run on my hosting (we are using shared GoDaddy hosting).

Can anyone tell me how can I upload files to WebDav\iDisk Server with PHP?

thanks in advance,
Michael

---

**UPD**

For those, who is searching for answer, here is a code snippet:

```
include("PEAR/HTTP/WebDAV/Client.php");
$client = new HTTP_WebDAV_Client_Stream();

$user="YOUR_LOGIN";
$pass = "YOUR_PASSWORD";

$dir = "webdav://".$user.":".$pass."@idisk.me.com/".$user."/";

$path = "";
var_dump($client->stream_open($dir."test.txt","w",null,$path));
$client->stream_write("HELLO WORLD!");
$client->stream_close();
$client->dir_opendir($dir,array());
var_dump($client->dirfiles);
```

Comment: instantiating $client = new HTTP_WebDav_Client_Stream() makes the server answer with a 500 error. I am using Apache2 with php5 have you got the same problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you could try the PEAR webdav client?

http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_WebDAV_Client/

Good luck :)

Comment: Oh, great, thanks a lot. Unfortunately it doesn't have nice docs, so it took a while to understand how it works (and get PEAR installed on shared hosting).

For those, who will want to upload files, I'll put a code snippet to my question.